# How to check health/query a Tempo datasource using the Grafana API - v9.1.6

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-tempo

I want to test the connectivity between Grafana(v9.1.6) and a Tempo datasource using the API. In the documentation, it appears that I can use the GET path /api/datasources/:datasourceId/health

(https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.1/developers/http_api/data_source/#check-data-source-health-by-id).

I have tried to use the calls described in the documentation without success.

The health test doesn't work. I got the following error. [image: Health test error]

I have tried querying the tempo data source, also getting an error. [image: Query error]

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That datasource health API is not mandatory. It is optional and 404 means that datasource developer didn't implemented it. So you can't use API in this current setup.

You may try to upgrade your Grafana - it may have Tempo health API implemented.